# Windows 7 - open with option for a file in opened compressed file

Tags: windows-7, zip, archiving

I'm not sure if this is possible or not but if it was it would make my life allot easier. What I want to do is get the "open with" option to open and make edits to a file in a .zip file **without** extracting the file. I am working on something and I need to open zip files and manipulate the data inside of them. What I am doing right now is copying the files I need to edit out of the archive, editing them, then copying them back into the archive. I am doing this dozens of times an hour. Is there a way to get the "open with" context option when you are viewing files in a compressed file in Windows Explorer? I am using Windows 7. Could anyone suggest a easier way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many third party file compression utilities are available that allow this. e.g. [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), [WinZip](http://www.winzip.com/downwz.htm), [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use an external program, like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [winrar](http://www.rarlab.com/) to manipulate the files